# How to use the .NET TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider in Android Studio (Kotlin)?

Tags: java, c#, android, kotlin, encryption

I have this code that I use in my C# (windows desktop) application; however, **I want to port my app to Android but I don't know any way that yields the same encryption/decryption results in Kotlin or Java**.
I have tried a couple of solutions till now but none of them worked for me (as they don't generate identical results to my C# applicattion):

I have tried this solution (but it didn't produce the same encryption result): https://www.programmersought.com/article/74841385394/

This one too: https://androidfreetutorial.wordpress.com/2017/03/14/android-encryptiondecryption-with-tripledes-3des-algorithm/

I want both my windows desktop (C#) app and my Android (Kotlin) app variants to produce the same encryption or decryption results.

My C# code:

```
private static string key = "123456789";

private static TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider CryptoServiceProvider()
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider myCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider myMD5_Service = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    myCryptoService.Key = myMD5_Service.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));
    myCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    return myCryptoService;
}

private static string Encrypt(string message)
{
    ICryptoTransform myEncryptor = CryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(myEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
}

private static string Decrypt(string message)
{
    ICryptoTransform myEncryptor = CryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
    byte[] _messageBytes = myEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_messageBytes, 0, _messageBytes.Length);
}
```

> *Encrypt("My message") => bRhsN5v76jrQcl54VrTKIAtsTAK0Hq3B*
>
> *Decrypt("bRhsN5v76jrQcl54VrTKIAtsTAK0Hq3B") => My message*

So in simple words, I want a way to transfer this code's logic to Kotlin (or Java if necessary).

Note 1: I can't change the encryption/decryption methods used in my C# application because that would mess everything for me... So I **CAN NEITHER** use any other cryptographic algorithm **NOR** modify the existing methods.

Note 2: I would really appreciate it if there is a solution using **Kotlin** instead of Java.

Comment: Pls see https://www.programmersought.com/article/74841385394/

Comment: This is simply encryption with Triple DES in two-key variant using MD5 for key derivation. The only pitfall I see is the encoding used for plaintext and key: MS specifies UTF-16LE (little andian) encoding with `Unicode`. Please post your most recent Kotlin/Java code and describe the problem.

Comment: Note that the C# code is _multiply_ insecure (broken MD5, deriving the key from a password with a digest, ECB) and not performant (Triple DES).